# "refs" of modal popup content giving 'undefined' once the popup is closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal popup as below

```
<ModalDialog  ref="modalAdd"  //this is bootstrap modal
  actions={
    <Button type="button" onClick={this.somemethod()} />
                }>
     <ModalContent>
            {this.testContent()}
      </ModalContent>
  </ModalDialog>
```

Am rendering `ModalContent` from `testContent()` method, as below.

```
 testContent = () =>{
         return <TestParameterEditor Data={this.state.result} ref="parameterEditor"/>;};. //here TestParameterEditor is classname
```

So now if i try to access 
`var parameters = _this6.refs["parameterEditor"].getParameters();` 
`_this6.refs["parameterEditor"]` is `undefined`.

Thanks. Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [callback ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute)

```
<ModalDialog ref={c => this.modal = c}
  actions={
    <Button type="button" onClick={this.somemethod()} />
                }>
     <ModalContent>
            {this.testContent()}
      </ModalContent>
  </ModalDialog>
```